# Textarea content to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, textarea

I have this textarea called personalInfos where i fill the infos in following format :

```
<p><span class="white">1966 - '69</span><br/> text .... </p>
```

When i submit it to database, it gets saved ok, same format. When i retrieve the code from database to admin textarea it gets filled ok.

My only problem is on front end where i get displayed the code as text not rendered as html code. So basiclly i see it on the page like this :

```
<p><span class="white">1966 - '69</span><br/>
```

Comment: PHP version? How do you insert it to database?

Comment: Could you add some information about how you retrieve the data from the database for example ? Or a link to a demo page ?

Comment: I got a custom db class which i call it for all mysql operations. 
For retrieving on front page i use this code :

$infos = new mysql("infos", "", "");
while($infos ->fetch_array())
echo $infos ->body;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have a look at [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

**Example**

```
$str = '<p><span class="white">1966 - \'69</span><br/> text .... </p>';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($str);
```

Also make sure to escape the single quotes as well.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you display fetched code parsed processed by `htmlentities()` or similar function. This is in most cases the way to go to avoid planting i.e. html in comments. So simply stop doing this after fetching (or insert - depends where you do so) and your content will be outputed as literaly HTML and properly processed by web browser.

Comment: Technically "yes", but logically "no" as this is not a solution but workaround. If you do not want some content processed that way or another, just stop processing it.

Comment: Isn't `htmlentities` sometimes used to prevent some SQL attacks?

Comment: Yes it is. By those who do not understand what they do. Those who do understand, use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or other method that is especially for that purpose.